# how do media queries increase site performance for mobile users

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've read that using media queries to change a site for a mobile device is good because it is less overhead and phones have less download speed. But how does that help? Can I do anything but just hide the elements I don't want seen on the mobile device? it still has to download the hidden elements. So what's the gain? I'm quite confused.

Comment: They could change which version of CSS background images are used, which would decrease bandwidth a bit. But I agree, this is really about usability than "performance"

Comment: You use media queries to change the look of your site to accommodate different devices which may have different resolutions. It's not really just about hiding things, it's more about enhancing the user experience. through different layout/content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of Responsive/Adaptive Website Design is not so much on making the size of your web page or it's assets smaller... It's about making content accessible and readable for people that are viewing your website on a Mobile Device. I would never say to hide elements just because someone is on a mobile device, I would say design and develop accordingly so the content is more presentable on a Mobile and or Tablet device.

Per your gain statement; The gain that you receive from designing and developing a website that is catered not only to desktop users, but mobile and tablet users as well. More people will be less prone to leave and more prone to stay and check out your content.

**You can read more up on Responsive Website Design below:**

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/how-to-get-started-with-responsive-web-design/1769

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

**You may also read more about the benefits of Responsive Website Design below:**

http://www.loungelizard.com/web-design-blogs/design/the-benefits-of-responsive-web-design/

http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/responsive-web-design-the-ultimate-guide-for-online-marketers

***Quick Note: Media Queries go hand-in-hand with Responsive/Adaptive Website Design.***

Hope this helped!

Comment: thank you very much for these links. i've only skimmed them so far (noting, however, that only one of them has a mobile-responsive website, and even on it, the same images are still served whether iphone or desktop). But I will definitely give them all a thorough read. I agree with catering to mobile browsers is important, as i am frequently frustrated by seeing a site on my phone and getting very long scrollbars in both directions. I'm just trying to determine if it's simpler and better for the user to go ahead and make a mobile site. It doesn't have to have

Comment: [decreased functionality](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/22/separate-mobile-responsive-website-presidential-smackdown/), i just wonder if it's easier to make, and can provide faster load times to mobiles. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Through media queries and CSS you don't just "hide" the content. Depending on how you set it up, you're not just hiding the content - it's not getting loaded.

You can also use media queries to choose image resolution, depending on the viewport. You can send lower-resolution images to mobile devices and hi-res to retina displays.

See:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

http://menacingcloud.com/?c=highPixelDensityDisplays

http://www.leemunroe.com/responsive-design/